# What's the best database for my data structure?

Tags: sql, nosql, grouping

I have two data structures that I need to store in a database. At this point, I'm relatively sure that SQL and any relational database types wouldn't work, but I'm also not sure what alternatives I have and/or which of those alternatives would be best. If there is a reasonable way to implement these structures in mySQL or something similar, I'm open to the idea.

Structure 1:

A nested tree diagram, where nodes are not defined ahead of time, and are instead generated from the data. I have a lot of strings that I need to separate into trees such that each branch node on the tree is empty and each leaf node contains a maximum of 200 strings, all beginning with the same prefix. I would use SQL, but considering I will regularly have upwards of 9.45x10^55 nodes (branch and leaf), I can't use the tree traversal method; adding a single node would take too much time.

Structure 2:

I have an array of the leaf nodes from the above structure, however, every  leaf node has its own data associated with it, yet not contained within it.

From my (extremely limited) understanding of SQL, the second structure can be implemented in mySQL or something similar. The problem is, I need to be able to retrieve individual nodes from the 2nd structure, instead of the entire array of nodes. Also, I don't know the length of the array ahead of time, so I can't simply make a table with a certain number of columns available for each node: I'd end up having over 9.09x10^55 columns, when I will regularly be only using 5 or less.

If you have any recommendations as to what kind of database I could use to implement these structures relatively easily, or any advice pertaining to the implementation itself, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You make a tree in SQL by adding one single column to your table named`parent_id` which refers to the id of the parent in the same table. Using a SQL engine like SQL-Server you can even do recursive queries.

Comment: @juergend How do I then retrieve or add data from leaf nodes without having to iterate through the entire list?

Comment: If you have the ID of the leave you can select all children with `where parent_id = your_leave_id`.

Comment: Yes, but the entire point is that I only know the ID of the root node

Comment: How do you identify the leaf if you only have the root?

Comment: That's the only one I definitely have. Each branch node can have up to 58 child nodes, but it also might have no child nodes, and the leaf nodes can all have different depths on the tree. As such, I don't know the parent node I am looking for, because I might be looking for multiple parent nodes at once.

Comment: As a curiosity, considering the fact the number of atoms in our solar system is about [1.2x10^57](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195522) what data could possibly have 9x10^55 nodes? Care to share?

Comment: @blueCat I'm working with hashes encoded in base58. 35 characters long.